# Difficulties in using categorial covariates in combined boxplot in ggplot / R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please find `My Data "kirecur"`below.

`kirecur$ki67in` 0, 1 and 2 each represent a patient group with specific patient characteristics. `kirecur$time.yr` is the time to an event.

I want three boxplots combined in one plot illustrating time to the event based on different patient categories, i.e. `kirecur$ki67in`

I have written the following

```
ggplot(kirecur, aes(ki67in,time.yr)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(ki67in, 1), colour=c("red", "blue", "green")))
```

Which gave an error: Error: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (29): group, colour, x, y`

I changed the script to `... colour=c("red")))`, which gave the following plot:

[image]

I need to add 1) different colored lines around each boxplot and 2) different color fills within each boxplot.

Intuitively, it seem there must be a way easier approach than I am currently doing. It seem quite simple to get three different boxplots with different color lines and fills - yet, I am stuck.

```
My Data    
kirecur <- structure(list(time.yr = c(0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.41666666666667, 
    3.16666666666667, 3.25, 4.08333333333333, 4.41666666666667, 4.5, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.75, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5, 
    6.16666666666667, 7.41666666666667, 7.5, 7.66666666666667, 9.83333333333333, 
    10.3333333333333), ki67in = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 
    0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("time.yr", "ki67in"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(16L, 
    20L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 35L, 40L, 53L, 
    54L, 60L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 87L, 111L, 112L, 
    116L, 159L, 171L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the *fill* argument of `aes` in place of *colour* argument while running `factor` on your groupings. Below also adds whisker ends to boxplots:

```
ggplot(kirecur, aes(ki67in, time.yr, fill = factor(ki67in))) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +       # FOR WHISKERS
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(ki67in, 1))) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="ki67in"))
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: what if I want to customize the colors, eg by typing "#999999" etc? Thank you for your reply

Comment: Nvm; I used + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) and it worked.

Comment: Glad to help and that you found a solution to your specific needs. Happy coding!